# Why is mouse position hook state inside my recursion not updating?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am doing a GSAP animation where an image moves wherever the mouse position is

I have a `useMousePosition` hook which returns the `x` and `y` mouse position

```
const useMousePos = () => {
    const [mousepos, setMousepos] = useState({ x: 0, y: 0 });
    
    // update mouse position when moving the mouse
    useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener('mousemove', getMousePos);

        () => {
            window.removeEventListener('mousemove', getMousePos)
        }
    }, []);

    // Gets the mouse position
    const getMousePos = (e: MouseEvent) => {
        let posx = 0;
        let posy = 0;

        if (!e) {
            e = window.event as any;
        }

        if (e.pageX || e.pageY) {
            posx = e.pageX;
            posy = e.pageY;
        } else if ((e.clientX || e.clientY) && typeof document.body !== 'undefined') {
            posx = e.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft + document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
            posy = e.clientY + document.body.scrollTop + document.documentElement.scrollTop;
        }

        setMousepos({ x: posx, y: posy })
    };

    return [mousepos];
};
```

And from my Component:

```
const WorkItemMenu: React.FC<IProps> = ({ title, description, imgURL }) => {
    const el = useRef<HTMLAnchorElement | null>(null);
    const [mousepos] = useMousePos();
    const requestId = useRef<any>(null);

    const onElMouseEnter = () => {
        loopRender();
    }

    const loopRender = () => {
        if (!requestId.current) {
            requestId.current = requestAnimationFrame(render);
        }
    } 

    const render = () => {
        requestId.current = undefined;

        console.log( mousepos) // ALWAYS RETURN THE SAME POSITION FROM LAST MOUSEOVER??

        // ...

        // loop
        loopRender();
    }

    return (
        <>
            <a ref={el} onMouseEnter={onElMouseEnter} onMouseLeave={onElMouseLeave} className="menu__item" data-img="/assets/images/projects/foodie/foodie-cover-mobile.jpg">
                <span className="menu__item-text"><span className="menu__item-textinner !font-primary">{title}</span></span>
                <span className="menu__item-sub">{description}</span>
                <div ref={reveal} className="hover-reveal" style={{ perspective: '1000px', opacity: 0, transform: 'translate(160.464px, -150.274px), rotate(-11.3103deg)' }}>
                    <div ref={revealInner} className="hover-reveal__inner" style={{ opacity: 0, transform: 'rotateY(90deg) scale(0.8694, 0.8694)' }}>
                        <div ref={revealImage} className="hover-reveal__img" style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${imgURL})`, filter: 'blur(3.4822px) brightness(1.4353)', transform: 'translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px) scale(1.1306, 1.1306)' }}>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </>
    );
};
```

Why does the `mousepos` inside the render always return same position from last mouseover?

Comment: It's been a while since I used React hooks, but are you sure the addEventListener and removeEventListener are called at the right moments?

Comment: @paddotk Yes. The position logs correctly when console.log placed outside the render.

Comment: I think this is related to the way the custom hook is used. Since it doesn't have anything to do with React specifically, such as rendering or tapping into the lifecycle, I think you're better off adding the eventlistener in your component (once upon mounting) and turning useMousePos into a plain javascript function. This way you can be sure it doesn't do any funky stuff with rendering, looping etc.